# Matched Geromety transition not "smooth"

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to use Matched Geometry to transition from one view to another. I've attached the video, as you can see, it's not "smooth". There is a fade on the left and right side of the burger as it transitions. What I doing wrong?

```
struct FullView: View {
    var namespace: Namespace.ID
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image("b4")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: getRect().width / 1.5)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "burger", in: namespace)
            Text("Baconator")
                .font(.title)
                .bold()
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "title", in: namespace)
            Text("The Baconator sandwich is a cheeseburger sold by the international fast-food restaurant chain Wendy's.")
                .font(.caption)
                .padding(.vertical)
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct MiniView: View {
    var namespace: Namespace.ID
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image("b4")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "burger", in: namespace)
            Text("Baconator")
                .font(.title)
                .bold()
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "title", in: namespace)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showingFull = false
    @Namespace private var namespace
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black.opacity(0.2)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            if (showingFull) {
                FullView(namespace: namespace)
            } else {
                MiniView(namespace: namespace)
                    .frame(width: getRect().width / 3)
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation(.spring()) {
                showingFull.toggle()
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Animation video link: https://streamable.com/tg2eij